# I got this error coding in visual basic to type 'Double' is not valid.' I was calculating the area of a triangle

Tags: vb.net

The code produces the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnArea_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnArea.Click
        If IsNumeric(TxtBase.Text) = False Then
            MsgBox("Please enter numbers only")
            TxtBase.Clear()
            TxtBase.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If IsNumeric(TxtHeight.Text) = False Then
            MsgBox("Please enter munbers only")
            TxtHeight.Clear()
            TxtHeight.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim base As Double
        Dim height As Double
        Dim area As Double

        height = TxtHeight.Text
        base = TxtBase.Text

        area = 0.5 * (base * height)
        area = TxtArea.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The error message tells you what need to know: you are tryting to assign the value auf a *String* property (```.Text``` of a Textbox) to a vairbale that you defined as *Double*. You need to convert the String data to a fitting numeric data type first. There are numerous ways, e.g. [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0) or [System.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-7.0) or VB's [CType function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function)

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  I think the issue should be blindingly obvious if you step through the code.  (Hint: Look at what you do with the calculated area.)

Comment: @HelO'Ween Agreed that the message points you in the right direction, but in this specific case, it isn't a problem with parsing, as there is already an `IsNumeric` check on the values that are expected to be user-entered.  It's a logic error in the code.

Comment: @Craig: I have to disagree. ```IsNumeric()``` only tells you if a string can be _interpreted_ as a number. It doesn't do the actual data type conversion that's needed to assign the value of a string variable to a numeric variable. And that's the issue he's dealing with, as the error message clearly points out.

Comment: But if it can be interpreted as a number, I would expect the subsequent conversion to work.  Does `IsNumeric` pass an empty string?  If not, then this isn't the problem.  Frankly, I think the problem is pretty obvious with even a little bit of mental analysis of what's going on later in the program, and it has nothing to do with conversion or parsing, it's a basic error with an inversion of the direction of an assignment.

Comment: To be fair, my initial assumption was the same as yours and I even flagged for a duplicate on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
height = TxtHeight.Text
base = TxtBase.Text
```

This retrieve data as a string. So you need to convert that before assigning to `height` and `base`.

```
height = CDbl(TxtHeight.Text)
base = CDbl(TxtBase.Text)
```

Comment: This isn't the problem.  There are already checks on whether these values are numeric, and VB will happily insert conversions behind the scenes when `Option Strict` is `Off` (as it clearly is in this case since otherwise it wouldn't compile).

Comment: But it TextBox.Text always return string values.

Comment: VB with `Option Strict Off` will insert conversions from string to double.  These will fail at runtime if the string doesn't parse to a double.  In fact, that's the kind of error that is produced in this case, *but it's a bit of a red herring caused by the actual logic error in the code which is doing an assignment in the wrong direction.*